# How to make the responsive visibility classes available when customizing imports in zurb foundation 3

Tags: media-queries, workflow-foundation, compass-sass

Using zurb foundation 3 because i need support for older ie browsers :(
I installed the foundation gem using a bundle so i can specify version 3.2.

The top of foundation's app.scss has these lines:

```
// Comment out this import if you are customizing you imports below
@import "foundation";
// ----------------------------------------
// Import specific parts of Foundation by commenting the import "foundation"
// and uncommenting what you want below. You must uncomment the following if customizing
```

and since i do want to customize my imports i have commented out the @import "foundation" line.

these lines seem to indicate that they are necessary to use foundation's grid:

```
//Must include next two for semantic grid to work
@import "foundation/mixins/respond-to";
@import "foundation/mixins/semantic-grid";
@import "modular-scale";
@import "foundation/common/globals";
```

i assumed they would include the media queries necessary to support the visibility classes, but this looks like it is not so.  when i add a class of "hide-for-small" to an element it is visible regardless and looking at the output css, there are no mqs in there.

So how does one single out and include the media queries that come with the foundation 3.2 framework?

Answer (score 0):

went here https://github.com/zurb/foundation/tree/3-2-stable/scss/foundation/components/modules

and found the name of the module, _mqueries.scss

so add this to your imports

```
@import "foundation/components/modules/mqueries";
```

and your're good!